# Select multiple words, one at a time, then replace them all

Tags: vimscript, replace, selection

Goal: Select multiple words, one at a time, then replace them all.

[image: visual studio feature select and replace]

I'm new to Vim; I come from Visual Studio. I would like to achieve one important feature that helped me a lot in my productivity: Select multiple words, one at a time, and then replace them all.

I know there is a Vim way of replacing using:

```
:% s/target-word/replacement/gc
```

But as you can see it's still a lot to write compared to its counterpart in VS Code. Could someone help me with a vim script or a plugin to achieve this in the most similar way?

- imagine that I already have selected the word with `viw`, for example.
- then I want to have a single command to select the next match.
- then start writing and see those changes written in real-time or after hitting `Esc`.

**[Edit] Accepted answer**

Thanks D. Ben Knoble; you provided to me the more convenient and practical answer. As the main goal is to change a word locally, the combination `*cgn` Is perfect.

As I'm changing the also the current word and `*` jumps me to the next match, what I add to go back to that word is `Ctrl + N`.

`* Ctrl + N cgn` then `.`

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Vi&Vim SE. If you're open to a little advice, seeing as you're new to vim and assuming you'd like to become as proficient as you can, be open to solutions that don't work exactly as you've laid it out but achieve the same thing..using "the Vim way". (I can't promise there will be a superior Vim way for this particular question so consider that general advice. Cheers.)

Comment: @BLayer Thanks, Vim has many things that I really love, like marks! and I'm really fast moving around, I just miss this incredibly useful feature, as also searching in the project just pressing `Ctrl + F` to search for a match in the whole project, now `:vimgrep /match/g **/*` I just want to check in the community if someone figgered out something more efficient to do these things.

Comment: @Sam also `:grep -R match`, depending on `grepprg` (I use ripgrep, so it’s really easy to do such a project wide search), `:tselect` if you have tags setup, `:find` if you know the file... there are many ways to search and navigate :)

Comment: I use registers a lot. Something like, while on the word, `"ayiw` to yank the word to register `a`, I mainly increment the number by a random number then do  `"byiw`. Then I use `%s/ (CTRL-ra)/(CTRL-rb)/gc` where `(CTRL-ra)` puts register a into the search part of the replace. Then `gc` goes match by match and you can replace or not. Generally I replace all because I know I need to. If i need to check they changed I use  `:g//` and expect no matches. Not a dev so maybe not what you're looking for.

Comment: @Steve , Thanks! actually, this is very useful, I didn't know any other way to actually "copy" the word of a file to use it in the vim command line. If I understand correctly:
"<key>  : start the register and then
yiw        : yank internal word, manage to "copy" the word to the registry
finally with CTRL+r<key> you "paste it"  in the vim command line.
Thanks for this useful tip!

Comment: A couple of notes: if you have a new question do *not* edit the original one; instead, ask a new one ([howto])—I've removed the edited-in new question, but you can get to it from the edit history if you like. Also, did you perhaps mean `N` (shift-n) instead of Ctrl-N?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, thanks, I'll take a note on that, yes I meant `Ctrl-N` but I added nnoremap **`` to `.vimrc` so that `*` won't take me to the next match.

Comment: @sam Hi. Exactly right. You can put the register directly with `"a[pP]` etc. Copying to a register in `:g` is useful as well eg `:g/{pattern}/y A will append matches in register a. You have to clear the register first with `qa` or `:let @a=''`` . http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/12.html might help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I’m assuming all the things to change are the same. If not, I would probably proceed with either multiples of the steps below, or combine all the patterns into a single substitute pattern.

So, not really what you asked for, but:

```
*cgn
```

Breakdown:

- `*`: start a search for the word under the cursor (`g*` if you don’t want the word boundaries)
- `c`change
- `gn` the next match

So you put your cursor somewhere in a word, press `*cgn`, type the replacement, hit `<esc>`, and then hit `.` to change the next occurence.

If you already searched for the word, ignore the `*` and just `cgn`.

These are somewhat equivalent to

```
%substitute/\<<C-r>=expand('<cword>')<cr>\>/replacement/gc
```

and

```
%substitute//replacement/gc
```

---

If you want to do this with a visually-selected pattern, I would `y`ank it, followed by

```
%substitute/<C-r>"//replacement/gc
```

(Add word boundaries `\<\>` as needed)

---

If you want to substitute in a narrower region, than the whole file (`%`), use ranges (and remember that in visual mode, `:` automatically populates the range `'<,'>`, which is also the range `*`, which is all the lines in the selection). These can be quite powerful, and a full overview is out-of-scope (`:help [range]`).

---

A slightly more advanced option: do a search (`:grep`, `:vimgrep`, &c.) or some other operation that fills the quickfix list (`:cexpr`, `:make`) and then

```
cdo substitute/pat/repl/flags
```

Or `:cfdo %substitute` if you know you want the whole of each file.

Don’t forget to `:cfdo update` or just `:wall` afterwards.

---

There do exist multi-cursor-emulation plugins for vim. I can’t recommend any, never having used them, but they are out there.

Really, though, learning how to use commands like `:substitute`, `:global`, `.`, operators like `c`, `d`, and all the other motions and such can be, *in the long term*, more efficient. It does require breaking some learned habits and thought-processes, however, and it’s not for everyone. Fear not. You can make vim whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for, I like things to be simple and fast to type, the Linux mentality, this way I won't be needing any plugin. I'm aiming for the *long term*, thanks this really improves my productivity, first I was jumping with `w` and `cw`, then with `:%s/match/replacement/gc`, now for faster and local things I can use `*cgn`, thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: The existence of multi-cursor plugins was exactly why I posted my initial comment. I was hoping you wouldn't end up with that as your choice. They are square pegs in round holes in terms of their fit in the Vim universe. Glad you found a solution that you like that follows "the Vim way" © ®. ;)

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to press `*` when your cursor is on the word you want to replace, `phrase` in this case, which will search for that word (very useful in general!) It will use `\<phrase\>` as the pattern: the `\>` are word boundaries (similar to `\b` in Perl-style regexps) so that it won't match `phrases`.

You can then use `:%s//sentence/g`; to replace `phrase` with `sentence`. If you omit the search pattern in `:s` then it will automatically use the current search pattern. I find that this is generally a more convenient way to do search previews than the `/c` flag: search for something: verify it matches what you want, and use `:s//replace`.

---

The current search pattern is stored in the `@/` register, which is a variable you can read and write; for example if you want to use `phrase` without the word boundaries:

```
:echo @/
\<phrase\>

:let @/ = 'phrase'
:echo @/
phrase

:%s//sentence
```

---

This isn't exactly the live preview you asked for, which is something Vim doesn't really have right now. I find this is a reasonably efficient workflow. Generally speaking Vim isn't too good at these kind of live preview things and such; even the live search when you use `/` is actually fairly new and was added 3 years ago.

In NeoVim you can use `:set inccommand=nosplit` to show a preview in a split window, but this isn't in Vim yet. I can't really find an issue for it on the Vim tracker right now. I'm fairly sure I saw a plugin for this once, but I can't find that right now either

Comment: Thinking alike :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Martin, I knew about the star `*` operator to match the next word, but I didn't know that it was saved in the `@` variable, interesting. I also didn't know I could use this to ignore the first parameter in `:%s//replace`.  It's pretty great. I guess I would ask you, could you show me how to make a `nmap` or `inoremap` so we don't have to write the instruction `:%s//replace`? I would really appreciate it.
I'll edit my question to put more context.

Comment: @Sam note that it is stored in the search register (`:help quote/`) which is accessible via `@/`--as are most registers. We already have a Q somewhere about mapping `:%s//...` if I can find it

Comment: Writing commands is kind of how Vim works @Sam, which is probably different from VSCode. You can use `nnoremap <C-s> :%s//` to map it to control+s, for example. Basically mappings just send the keys you'd type (although you can do some more advanced things as well). To automatically add the `/g` flag and put the cursor in the correct position you can use `:nnoremap <C-s> :%s//g<Left><Left>`. You can also add the `*` beforehand, if you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

There are Vim plug-ins that emulate the "multiple cursors" feature from other editors such as Sublime or VS Code, for example, [mg979/vim-visual-multi](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi) (successor to the now deprecated [terryma/vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors).)

But since these plug-ins need to use Vim highlighting features to emulate multiple selections and they typically need to re-implement many Vim native movements, they are often limited in what they can do and they can be a little buggy.

There are many other Vim plug-ins implementing search and replace features. While they might not be as visually straightforward as the "multiple cursors" feature, they often work better in Vim. Some examples are:

- [dyng/ctrlsf.vim](https://github.com/dyng/ctrlsf.vim)
- [dkprice/vim-easygrep](https://github.com/dkprice/vim-easygrep)
- [wincent/ferret](https://github.com/wincent/ferret)

And many others. As it's often the case with Vim, there are tradeoffs with each choice, some will be better in specific situations, some will be more general. While you can get a lot done in terms of search and replace with built-in features of Vim, if you do consider adding external plug-ins, consider evaluating the ones in this list. A web search for "vim search and replace" will also point you at many more.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, acording to the repository terryma/vim-multiple-cursors. is deprecated, the new repository looks promising: https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi, I'll check on it and I'll let you know. The other three in the list seem very powerful when it comes to seach in the whole project, but I guess is not the use case I'm looking for, I want something local, in the same file, and fast so I don't have to type too many comands, that's why I'm incline to use try a mapping solution as a configuration. Thanks again for all the references!

Comment: @Sam Oh wow I didn't realize that! I had fixed a bug in vim-multiple-cursors a few months ago... Anyways, glad you found the replacement and I hope it helps you! Don't miss the answers from Ben and Martin, often without any plugins you can get a lot done already... Cheers!

Comment: @fibranden Thanks, yeah, sometimes the time comes and you know that you need a plugin, I just wanted to use all my options before doing it. I a nodejs developer I always consider if something can be done with plain javascript instead of adding yet another dependency to the node_modules... here I'm trying to apply the same with Vim. Thanks for everything!