# Perform operation on multi occurence variable

Tags: replace

I'm new to Vim and cursed coming from atom multi-cursor operation.

I can't seem an easy way to change the variable names. Say I needed to replace `bad_var` only in the function - How would you do it?

```
bad_var = 2 # must not be changed

def best_function_in_the_universe(bad_var):
    x = bad_var + 1
    print("hello")
    return bad_var
```

Comment: I've been trying the "autoc-compelte cgn" example here, and it looks like it's what I need. However, I don't follow the guide. Could you someone explain it in depth for a total beginner? https://medium.com/@schtoeffel/you-don-t-need-more-than-one-cursor-in-vim-2c44117d51db

Comment: Could you give use more information about what you mention as "autoc-compelte cgn"? Maybe some additional description or link may help.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/27812/10604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## On `cgn`

There are two concepts at play here: the change operator `c` and the motion or text-object it accepts. You may know that `cw` changes the text covered by the motion `w`, so roughly "change to the next word." (Change in this context means "delete and start Insert mode"; such a change is ended when you exit Insert mode with Escape.)

The argument to `c` in this case is the text-object `gn`, which is a rather special object that selects the next occurrence of the current search. So if you've searched `/foo`, `cgn` will jump to the next `foo`, delete it, and leave you in Insert mode. This is kind of like how `n` jumps to the match.

This is particularly handy for refactoring in a single file, because `*` searches the word under the cursor. So `*cgnbar<Esc>` when the cursor is on `foo` changes the *next* occurrence of `foo` to `bar`. And when you repeat the change with `.`, the next occurrence is changed in the same way, and so on.

## Other Approaches

One draw back is that the search is buffer-specific, so if you're changing an exported name `*cgn` is slightly less convenient. You'll need to load the files that contain that name (say, in to the arg list or buffer list), and use `:argdo normal! 9999.` or some such hackery.

Instead, you might want to try `:grep foo` and `:cdo substitute/foo/bar` or similar (alternatives include `:vimgrep`, `:cfdo` with `:%substitute`, the `/g` or `/c` flags, or even just `:cnext` with `.` as appropriate).

Having unit tests or a compiler available to check the changes helps with the feedback loop, especially if you've already got `:make` working. This makes yet another approach: make the initial change to the export, then `:make` and use the quickfix list as before to correct the errors. Repeat until finished.

Answer (score 2):

Without any plugin and using just the power of vim itself, I would do a visual selection of the lines that should be affected and replace any occurrence of a pattern with what I want to have.

In your example, I'd place the cursor on the line with `def best_function_in_the_universe`, do `V}` to visually select everything until the next blank line. Then use the `:help substitute` command to replace `:'<,'>s/bad_var/good_var/` (vim will fill in the cryptic stuff between ":" and "s", it means to operate on the selected lines only).

Next steps:

If `bad_var` were to be present as part of another word, e.g. `not_a_bad_var` and I would not want to replace it, I'd add word boundaries like so `:'<,'>s/\<bad_var\>/good_var/`.

You might also be interested in replacing more than one match per line by appending `g`. Or confirm every replacement by appending `c`. Command would look like this: `:'<,'>s/\<bad_var\>/good_var/gc`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @Friedrich is the 'right' (Vim) one.

But here are three alternative that could be worth considering.

### Vim-Visual-Multi

But coming from Atom you could be interested by the [Vim-Visual-Multi](https://github.com/mg979/vim-visual-multi) plugin that offers support for multiple cursor.

### LSP Rename

An alternative for your use case is to use the support of the language server. Using the [Coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) plugin with the `coc-pyright` extension (`:CocInstall pyright`) you could use the rename functionality (`rn` in normal mode) to rename a variable.

### LSP Select

If you have the [Coc](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) plugin installed the `vaf` keystrokes let you select the entire method in one go before you apply a substitution (`'<,'>s/\C\<bad_var\>/good_var/gc`)

Comment: Thank you for the praise. By the way, I've been in the business long enough to accept that whatever works is the "right" solution :)